# Run WP8 apps on ARM7-based Windows RT Tablet

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, tablet-pc

I am making a simple Windows Phone 8 game on C#, Visual Studio 2013. I want to try my application on WinRT tablet(not visual studio) as Android devices do. But my PC couldn't connect to tablet, I've already tried Visual Studio 2013 Remote Tools, it didnt works for me. Any help? sorry for my English.(I have Asus Vivo Tab)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike Apple and Google, where the OS on the phone is the same on the tablet, that is not what Microsoft came up with.
The OS on the Microsoft's phone is Windows Phone (current version 8) while ARM tablets have an ARM version of Windows 8 (current 8.1). According to Microsoft they do share the same kernel so it would be a matter of time to have the same app running on both kinds of devices.

So, as of today, if you want your app to run on Windows Phone and on Windows tablets, you **have** to have two different binaries uploaded to the markets.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run Windows Phone apps on Windows ARM tablets.

Comment: Don't you just love Microsoft? I think this is a real missed opportunity.. but I guess this has to do with the difference in architecture between winRT and WP8?

Comment: Maybe it will come in a future version, it seems logical.

Comment: Yes, it will. One Windows project.

Answer (score 1):

Windows ARM tablets don't support Windows phone apps.